# presentViewController:animated:completion: causes my program to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have a RootViewController that presents FirstViewController with the instance method presentViewController:animated:completion:. I have a log message ("Presenting") in the method; it appears so I know my root is being called on in my FirstViewController, but for some reason the message gets logged continuously before the program crashes.

**RootViewController**

```
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent
                  animated:(BOOL)flag
              completion:(void (^)(void))completion {

     NSLog(@"Presenting");

    [self presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
}
```

**FirstViewController (where I call on the method)**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    MyRootController *root = [[MyRootController alloc] init];
    [root presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"asdhflkajshdfl %@...", [self presentingViewController]);

}
```

I'm not sure how I can have the method be executed only once. This is my first time using the method, but I assumed that the message would be logged only once.

Comment: shouldn't `self` be presenting `root` ?

Comment: I thought root is presenting self? Like RootViewController presents FirstViewController which I thought was self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want to know, when `presentViewController...` is called (EDIT: ... , because there's only the log call and the call to the same method in it). You also probably want to call the super class method, so you need to use `super` instead of `self`:

```
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent
                  animated:(BOOL)flag
              completion:(void (^)(void))completion {

     NSLog(@"Presenting");
    // Note super here:
    [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
}
```

In your original code, you are calling the same method from within itself. This leads to the many log messages.